# Ajuda para determinar tamanho de vetor/matriz - Linguagem C

Tags: c, fopen

O que gostaria de fazer é colocar em um vetor ou matriz, informações de um arquivo `txt` sem conhecimento prévio do número de "entradas" para saber o tamanho do vetor ou matriz.

Com o tamanho do vetor ou matriz, eu poderei invocar a função `malloc` e então ler o conteúdo do arquivo.

Alguém poderia me aconselhar o melhor modo de fazer? Obrigado.

Comment: Boa tarde João, desculpe talvez eu não conheça o termo `entradas` em `C` (se é que é um termo), o que realmente você quer dizer com entradas? Você está se referendo ao `I/O`?

Comment: Boa tarde, ainda sou meio iniciante, talves não tenha me referido corretamente, o que eu quis dizer como entrada é alguma informação contida no arquivo txt que vai até \n, e apos isso seria outra entrada. Exemplo do que quero dizer: no arquivo teria: nome1 (espaço) idade1 (espaço) nome2 (espaço)... cada nome e idade seriam uma entrada, o nome1 seria a primeira entrada, a ideade1 seria a segunda e por ai vai...

Comment: Talves seria melhor eu ter dito em geral o que quero fazer e perguntado como fazer-lo. Eu quero colocar em um vetor ou matriz o conteudo de um arquivo, porem não sei o "tamanho" do arquivo para "por o tamanho do vetor"

Comment: @João, seja bem vindo ao [pt.so], você pode [edit] sua pergunta e colocar esses detalhes que você comentou nela, depois você pode navegar pelo [tour] e aprender um pouco mais sobre o SOpt

Comment: Veja se [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3747128/2556111) ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado, deu uma ajudada.

Comment: Sera que não seria melhor utilizar uma lista encadeada dinâmica ao invés de um vetor/matriz pra armazenar os dados? Assim você não tem que se preocupar com o número de entradas.

Answer (score 1):

Para saber o tamanho do arquivo, você pode ir ao fim do arquivo e então obter a posição:

```c
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
sz = ftell(fp);
```

E depois, você pode voltar ao começo do arquivo:

```c
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/238607/540552

Comment: Lembrando que esse método é especialmente útil no cenário onde todas as entradas tem tamanho fixo. Do contrario você não teria como calcular o numero de posições do vetor, mas sim a quantidade de memoria que você precisaria alocar pra colocar todo o conteúdo do arquivo na memória.

Answer (score 0):

Se as entradas têm um tamanho definido e único, tudo que você tem que fazer é pegar o tamanho do arquivo e dividir pelo tamanho da entrada. O resultado é o número de entradas.

Caso o tamanho das entradas variem, as coisas ficam um pouco mais difíceis, mas você pode tentar:

- Usar uma lista ligada ou uma árvore ou algum outro tipo de estrutura de dados;
- Fazer uma estimativa que não seja inferior ao número de entradas e deixar algumas posições do array sobrando no final caso você tenha superestimado o número;
- Percorrer o arquivo inteiro apenas para saber qual é o número de entradas e depois percorrer ele de novo para preencher o array.

Comment: Obrigado victor, o tamanho das entradas variam. Mas creio que não consegui me explicar em minha pergunta, então deixa tentar melhorar.. eu gostaria colocar em um vetor ou matriz o conteúdo de um arquivo, porem não sei o "tamanho" do arquivo para "por o tamanho do vetor". Você poderia me aconselhar a melhor maneira de realizar isto?

Comment: @João A minha outra resposta te ajuda?

Comment: Obrigado, mas não era bem isso que estava em mente, o fseek não da de fato a quantidade de entradas como eu queria, mas creio que o valor de bytes, ou estou enganado ? e eu ainda não cheguei nessa parte em meu aprendizado para utilizar bem essa função.. mesmo assim, muito obrigado