# Leitura de arquivo em C

Tags: c, arquivo

Estou fazendo um projeto em C, que é necessário a criação e leitura de um arquivo. Estou com dificuldade de implementar a leitura. Na leitura já tentei aplicar `fgets()`, `fscanf()` e o `fread()`. Mas nenhum deu certo. Alguém me sugere algo?

Agradeço desde já.

Segue o código:

```
main()
{
    //Declaração de variáveis

    Cliente *primeiro = NULL;
    int opcao;

    //Artificio para repetir o programa

    while (opcao != 5)
    {
        //Menu de opcoes

        printf("MENU\n");
        printf("<1> Novo cadastro de cliente \n");
        printf("<2> Listar clientes\n");
        printf("<3> Excluir cadastro de cliente\n");
        printf("<4> Alterar cadastrado de cliente\n");
        printf("<5> Sair");

       //lendo a opcao do menu
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nDigite a opcao desejada:");
        scanf("%d",&opcao);



    switch(opcao)
    {
        case 1:

        //Inserindo os clientes
        fflush(stdin);
        system("cls");
        printf("NOVO CADASTRO DE CLIENTE\n");
        primeiro = inserir_cliente(primeiro);
        getch();
        system("cls");
        break;

        case 2:
       //Listando os clientes
        system("cls");
        printf("CLIENTES CADASTRADOS\n");
        listar_cliente(primeiro);
        getch();
        system("cls");
        break;

        case 3:
        //excluir cliente
        system("cls");
        printf("EXCLUIR CLIENTES");
        primeiro = excluir_cliente(primeiro);
        getch();
        system("cls");
        break;

        case 4:
        //açterar informaçoes do cliente
        system("cls");
        printf("ALTERAR INFORMACOES DO CLIENTE");
        alterar_cliente(primeiro);
        getch();
        system("cls");
        break;

        case 5:
        //artificio para sair do programa.
        opcao = 5;
        break;

        default:
        system("cls");
        break;

    }
  }
}

Cliente* inserir_cliente(Cliente *primeiro)
{
    FILE *cli;

    cli = fopen("cadastrocliente.txt","a+");

    if(cli == NULL)
    {
        printf("Arquivo NAO pode ser aberto");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    Cliente novocliente;
    Cliente *atual = primeiro;
    char identificador = 'F';

    //Lendo as informaçoes do cliente.

    printf("\nNome:");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(novocliente.nome,40,stdin);
    printf("\n");

    printf("CPF:",135);
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(novocliente.cpf,15,stdin);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Codigo:",162);
    scanf("%u",&novocliente.codigo);
    printf("\n");


    //Verificando se o cadastro já existe.

    for(atual=primeiro; atual!=NULL; atual=atual->prox)
    {
        if(atual->codigo==novocliente.codigo)
        {
            identificador= 'V';
            break;
        }
    }
    if(identificador!='V' && (strlen(novocliente.nome)!=1 && strlen(novocliente.cpf)!=1))
    {
        //Alocando os espaços e guardando as informaçoes do cliente.
        Cliente* ClienteNovo=(Cliente*) malloc(sizeof(Cliente));
        strcpy(ClienteNovo->nome,novocliente.nome);
        strcpy(ClienteNovo->cpf,novocliente.cpf);
        ClienteNovo->codigo=novocliente.codigo;
        ClienteNovo->prox=primeiro;


        printf("Cadastro realizado com sucesso.");


        fprintf(cli,"%u\n",novocliente.codigo);
        fprintf(cli,"%s",novocliente.nome);
        fprintf(cli,"%s",novocliente.cpf);

        system("cls");

        printf("Codigo: %u",novocliente.codigo);
        printf("\nNome: %s",novocliente.nome);
        printf("CPF: %s",novocliente.cpf);


        getchar();
        fclose(cli);
        //system("cls");

        printf("\n\nPRESSIONE QUALQUER TECLA PARA VOLTAR AO MENU PRINCIPAL.");
        return ClienteNovo;
    }

     else
    {
        printf("Cadastro INVALIDO",160);
    }

}

void listar_cliente(Cliente* primeiro)
{

    FILE *cli;

    cli = fopen("cadastrocliente.txt","r");

    if(cli == NULL)
    {
        printf("Arquivo NAO pode ser aberto.\n");
        system("pause");
        //return 0;
    }



    Cliente* atual; //Ponteiro para percorrer a lista sem perder a referência do primeiro elemeto da lista.


        //Imprimindo os clientes da lista, e suas respectivas informações.


    for(atual = primeiro; atual != NULL; atual = atual -> prox)
    {
        printf("\n Nome:");
        printf("%s", atual -> nome);
        printf("\n CPF:",162);
        printf("%s", atual -> cpf);
        printf("\n Codigo:");
        printf("%u",atual -> codigo);
        printf("\n\n");

    }

    if(primeiro == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nNENHUM CLIENTE CADASTRADO.\n");
    }


    fclose(cli);


    printf("\n\nPRESSIONE QUALQUER TECLA PARA VOLTAR AO MENU PRINCIPAL.");
}

Cliente* excluir_cliente(Cliente* primeiro)
{
    FILE *cli;

    cli = fopen("cadastro.txt","a");

     if(cli == NULL)
    {
        printf("Arquivo NAO pode ser aberto");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

     Cliente *anterior=NULL;// ponteiro para saber o elemento anterior ao elemento atual da lista.
     Cliente *atual=primeiro;//Ponteiro para percorrer a lista sem perder o primeiro elemento da lista.
     unsigned long int codigo=0;


     //Requisitando e lendo o código do cliente a ser excluido.
     printf("\nCodigo do cliente a ser excluido:",162,161);
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%u",&codigo);

     //Procurando o cliente na lista

     while(atual!= NULL && atual->codigo!=codigo)
     {
         anterior=atual;
         atual=atual->prox;
     }

     //Mensagem caso o cliente não seja encontrado.

     if(atual==NULL)
     {
         printf("\n Cliente NAO encontrado.",198);
         printf("\n\nPRESSIONE QUALQUER TECLA PARA VOLTAR AO MENU PRINCIPAL.");
         return primeiro;
     }

     //Excluindo o primeiro cliente da lista.

     if(anterior==NULL)
     {
         printf("\n Conteudo EXCLUIDO com sucesso.",163,161);
         primeiro=atual->prox;
     }
     //Excluindo um cliente do meio da lista.
     else
     {
         printf("\n Conteudo excluido com sucesso.",163,161);
         anterior->prox=atual->prox;

     }
     //Desalocando o espaço da memoria.
     free(atual);
     printf("\n\nPRESSIONE QUALQUER TECLA PARA VOLTAR AO MENU PRINCIPAL.");
     return primeiro;

     getchar();
    fclose(cli);

}

void alterar_cliente(Cliente* primeiro)
{
     char nome_substituto[40], cpf_substituto[40];
     unsigned long int codigo;
     Cliente* atual=primeiro;

     //Requisitando e lendo o codigo do cliente a ser alterado.

     printf("\n\nCodigo do cliente a ser alterado:",162);
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%u",&codigo);

     //Procurando o cliente na lista.
     while(atual!=NULL && atual->codigo!=codigo)
     {
         atual= atual->prox;
     }

     //Alterando os dados do cliente.

     if(atual!=NULL)
     {
         printf("\nNovo Nome:");
         fflush(stdin);
         fgets(nome_substituto,40,stdin);
         strcpy(atual->nome,nome_substituto);

         printf("\nNovo cpf:",135);
         fflush(stdin);
         fgets(cpf_substituto,40,stdin);
         strcpy(atual->cpf,cpf_substituto);

         printf("\n Dados ALTERADOS com sucesso.");

     }else{
         printf("\n\n Cliente NAO Encontrado",198);
     }

     printf("\n\n\nPRESSIONE QUALQUER TECLA PARA VOLTAR AO MENU PRINCIPAL.");
}
```

Comment: Há várias partes aonde você usa números que serão utilizados no `printf`, como por exemplo `printf("CPF:",135);` e `printf("\nCodigo do cliente a ser excluido:",162,161);` - Porque os números estão lá se eles não serão usados nunca?

Answer (score 3):

Use `fread` e `fwrite`. Para usá-los, você deve [abrir o arquivo em modo binário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42564/132).

O tamanho do arquivo é obtido por meio de [`fseek` seguido de `ftell`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44394/132).

Aqui vai uma forma de inserir ou atualizar o cliente no arquivo. Se o código não existir, ele insere. Se existir ele altera:

```
// Estrutura que mostra como o cliente é salvo no arquivo.
// Isso é diferente da forma como ele é representado em memória por não haver o ponteiro prox.
// Outras diferenças podem vir a ser possíveis também.
typedef struct {
    char nome[41]; // 40 caracteres mais o terminador nulo.
    char cpf[16]; // 15 caracteres mais o terminador nulo.
    int codigo;
} ClienteArquivo;

void inserir_ou_alterar_cliente_no_arquivo(Cliente* cliente) {
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("cadastrocliente.dat", "a+b");

    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        printf("Arquivo NAO pode ser aberto.\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    fseek(arquivo, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int tamanho_do_arquivo = ftell(fp);
    int numero_de_registros = tamanho_do_arquivo / sizeof(ClienteArquivo);

    ClienteArquivo lido;

    // Percorre o arquivo até achar a posição aonde o cliente está lá.
    // Ao término, i será o número do registro no qual o cliente está,
    // ou então será o fim do arquivo (numero_de_registros) se o cliente
    // não for encontrado.
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numero_de_registros; i++) {
        fseek(arquivo, i * sizeof(ClienteArquivo), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&lido, sizeof(ClienteArquivo), 1, arquivo);
        if (lido.codigo == cliente->codigo) break;
    }

    // Copia os dados do cliente.
    memset(&lido, 0, sizeof(ClienteArquivo)); // Limpa para evitar que eventuais lixos na memória acabem sendo escritos no arquivo.
    strcpy(lido.nome, cliente->nome); // Copia o nome.
    lido.nome[40] = 0; // Força o terminador nulo.
    strcpy(lido.cpf, cliente->cpf); // Copia o CPF.
    lido.cpf[15] = 0; // Força o terminador nulo.
    lido.codigo = cliente->codigo; // Copia o código.

    // Se terminou de percorrer o for e não achou no arquivo, então posiciona no final.
    if (i == numero_de_registros) fseek(arquivo, 0L, SEEK_END);

    // Escreve o cliente.
    fwrite(&lido, sizeof(ClienteArquivo), 1, arquivo);

    fclose(arquivo);
}
```

A exclusão é um pouco mais difícil, pois o tamanho do arquivo diminui neste caso. Além disso, excluir no meio do arquivo deixaria buracos. A solução é copiar o último registro do arquivo para a posição em que ocorreu a exclusão e então [fazer o tamanho do arquivo diminiur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/873653/540552).

```
void excluir_cliente_no_arquivo(Cliente* cliente) {
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("cadastrocliente.dat", "a+b");

    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        printf("Arquivo NAO pode ser aberto.\n");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    fseek(arquivo, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int tamanho_do_arquivo = ftell(fp);

    if (tamanho_do_arquivo != 0) {

        int numero_de_registros = tamanho_do_arquivo / sizeof(ClienteArquivo);

        ClienteArquivo ultimo;

        // Lê o último registro.
        fseek(arquivo, tamanho_do_arquivo - sizeof(ClienteArquivo), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&ultimo, sizeof(ClienteArquivo), 1, arquivo);

        ClienteArquivo lido;

        // Percorre o arquivo até achar a posição aonde o cliente está lá.
        // Ao término, i será o número do registro no qual o cliente está,
        // ou então será o fim do arquivo (numero_de_registros) se o cliente
        // não for encontrado.
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < numero_de_registros; i++) {
            fseek(arquivo, i * sizeof(ClienteArquivo), SEEK_SET);
            fread(&lido, sizeof(ClienteArquivo), 1, arquivo);
            if (lido.codigo == cliente->codigo) break;
        }

        // Se achou, substitui o registro encontrado com o último e diminui o arquivo.
        if (i < numero_de_registros) {
            fseek(arquivo, i * sizeof(ClienteArquivo), SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&ultimo, sizeof(ClienteArquivo), 1, arquivo);
            ftruncate(fileno(arquivo), tamanho_do_arquivo - sizeof(ClienteArquivo));
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
}
```

Por fim, você também vai precisar buscar um cliente no arquivo e retornar os seus dados:

```
ClienteArquivo* procurar_cliente_no_arquivo(int codigo) {
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("cadastrocliente.dat", "a+b");

    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        printf("Arquivo NAO pode ser aberto.\n");
        system("pause");
        return NULL;
    }

    ClienteArquivo *lido = (ClienteArquivo *) malloc(sizeof(ClienteArquivo));

    // Percorre o arquivo até achar a posição aonde o cliente está lá.
    // Ao término, i será o número do registro no qual o cliente está,
    // ou então será o fim do arquivo (numero_de_registros) se o cliente
    // não for encontrado.
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numero_de_registros; i++) {
        fseek(arquivo, i * sizeof(ClienteArquivo), SEEK_SET);
        fread(lido, sizeof(ClienteArquivo), 1, arquivo);
        if (lido.codigo == codigo) break;
    }

    // Se não encontrou, desaloca a memória alocada e retorna NULL.
    // Se encontrar retorna um ponteiro para a estrutura alocada. 
    if (i == numero_de_registros) {
        free(lido);
        lido = NULL;
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
    return lido;
}
```

Essa função acima retorna um ponteiro com os dados do cliente. Posteriomente você vai precisar criar um `Cliente` com base no `ClienteArquivo` retornado, vez que `ClienteArquivo` não tem ponteiro para o próximo registro. Você também não deve se esquecer de chamar o `free` no `ClienteArquivo` retornado quando não precisar mais dele. A função retornará `NULL` se não encontrar o cliente com o código procurado.

E então você só deverá manipular arquivos apenas por meio dessas funções. Nada de usar `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fread`, `fprintf` ou qualquer coisa assim que não seja dentro dessas três funções acima. Desta forma, você deixa as partes que manipulam os arquivos diretamente isoladas nestas funções, e evita que elas se espalhem e compliquem o resto da aplicação. Se você não quebrar essa regra, isso tornará as suas funções `inserir_cliente`, `listar_cliente`, `alterar_cliente` e `excluir_cliente` (bem como quaisquer outras que você precisar criar) muito mais simples e menos propensa a possíveis erros de programação, uma vez que você vai separar as funções que manipulam arquivo das funções que manipulam estruturas de dados em memória.

E atenção: estas funções são muito sensíveis quanto ao formato do arquivo! Se você criar ou alterar o arquivo `cadastrocliente.dat` por algum meio que não seja essas três funções, você vai acabar corrompendo o seu arquivo e deixando o seu programa maluco. Sempre que você alterar o formato de `ClienteArquivo`, recomendo destruir o arquivo anterior para evitar a possibilidade de manipular registros com formatos errados. E uma vez que ele agora é um arquivo binário, e não um arquivo texto, eu até mudei a extensão de `.txt` para `.dat`. Não tente manipular este arquivo no bloco de notas ou tratá-lo como se fosse texto.

Outras dicas:

- [Tenha cuidado com o `fflush(stdin)`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96012/132). O seu código não funcionará no linux! Além disso, se estiver no linux, você terá que usar `system("clear");` ao invés de `system("cls");`. Veja nessa resposta do link como resolver isso e dê uma lida nos comentários da resposta também.
- Não passe parâmetros inúteis no `printf`. Tais como por exemplo: `printf("CPF:",135);` e `printf("\nCodigo do cliente a ser excluido:",162,161);`, aonde o `135`, o `162` e o `161` são inúteis. Há vários lugares aonde você faz isso.
- Use 0 e 1 para falso e verdadeiro, ao invés de `F` ou `V`. O principal motivo é que esta é a forma padrão no C e também o código fica mais fácil de ler, pois você simplificaria `if (identificador == 'V')` ou `if (identificador != 'F')` para `if (identificador)`, e simplificaria o `if (identificador != 'V')` ou `if (identificador == 'F')` para `if (!identificador)`.
- Sempre que for usar `fclose`, certifique-se de que ele é usado em todos os possíveis caminhos da função. Na sua função `excluir_cliente`, por exemplo, isso não acontecia quando o cliente não era encontrado. Entretanto, se você manipular o arquivo apenas com as três funções acima e eliminar a manipulação de arquivos de todos os demais lugares, este problema desaparecerá.