# Como posso exportar o output para um arquivo de texto em C?

Tags: c, arquivo, txt

Quero passar o output do programa para um arquivo .txt, como eu faria?

Comment: Comecei a estudar c esse ano e ainda estou bem no começo, se puderem me sugerir que comandos e bibliotecas utilizar para resolver a minha dúvida acima, eu agradeceria muito

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Leitura de arquivo em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97052/leitura-de-arquivo-em-c)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Então se uma dúvida já foi resolvida em qualquer outro post eu não posso mais perguntar sobre ela?

Comment: Se está respondida lá, não tem porquê perguntar de novo - e obter a mesma resposta. Se a resposta lá não é o que precisa, deixe claro na pergunta o que você precisa que a resposta atual não responde.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss É porque naturalmente as palavras que eu usei para perguntar não são as mesmas que uma outra pessoa utilizou, então como saber em uma ocasião futura se a dúvida já foi respondida? Lembrando que nem sempre o search questions funciona perfeitamente, como eu disse, eu vou pesquisar usando as palavras x e a pessoa pode ter perguntado usando palavras y.

Comment: Nesses casos, em que procurou mas não achou, abra a pergunta sem medo. Se a resposta existir, alguém saberá e sinalizará como duplicata. Não é ruim ter a pergunta duplicata - elas, inclusive, ajudam a otimizar as buscas: da mesma forma que você não achou a resposta, outros poderiam não achar, mas agora achariam a sua pergunta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Entendi, e uma última dúvida, se vc puder responder claro, hoje eu fiz um post, que achei estar nos padrões no site, e foi reportado como off-topic, foi perguntando qual seria a linguagem ideial para fazer um tipo de programa lá, e inclusive o único que me respondeu também recebeu muitos downvotes, oq eu realmente não entendi, isso se aplicaria a mim que fiz a pergunta errada e não a ele que respondeu corretamente. Então eu gostaria de saber: Como eu posso ver se minha pergunta esta dentro dos padrões? Pois só estar relacionada com programação não parece ser o bastante.

Comment: Muitas das suas dúvidas já foram discutidas no [meta] ou já estão descritas no [tour].

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Mas eu só postei duas dúvidas

Comment: Dúvidas que apresentou nos comentários quanto ao funcionamento do site, não em relação às suas perguntas.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Oh entendo, me desculpe

Comment: Pessoalmente não consegui perceber a pergunta. Você quer guardar informações num arquivo .txt ? Ou fazer com que o que sai para a consola (por `printf`) seja redirecionado para um arquivo ? E o que quer dizer com "importar dados para a execução do programa em um arquivo externo" ?

Comment: @Isac na verdade eu tomei um txt como exemplo, acredito que seja mais fácil começar com arquivos de texto. Esquece a parte do "importar dados… externo", como eu faria pra exportar o output para um arquivo de texto? Finja que foi essa a minha pergunta

Comment: @Isac era isso sim, obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para redirecionar o output de um programa para um arquivo basta chamar da forma certa pelo terminal/linha de comandos:

Windows:

```
programa.exe > arquivo.txt
```

Unix

```
./programa > arquivo.txt
```

Analogamente pode usar `<` para utilizar um arquivo como *stream* de entrada, ou seja como se fosse o que iria escrever direto na consola para *input*:

```
programa < arquivo_entrada.txt
```

Pode até combinar os dois e usar um arquivo de entrada e outro de saida:

```
programa < arquivo_entrada.txt > arquivo_saida.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você deseja passar o output COMPLETO do programa para o arquivo, pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

Windows:

```
meuprograma.exe > arquivo.txt
```

Unix/Linux:

```
./meuprograma > arquivo.txt
```

Obs: Apenas um ">" vai substituir tudo que está dentro do arquivo, e dois ">>" vai acrescentar. Ambos vão criar um arquivo caso não existir!

Mas, se você deseja passar o output de dentro do seu programa, de uma variavel por exemplo, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
char Str[100];
FILE *arq;

arq = fopen("arquivo.txt", "wt"); //abre arquivo ou cria um

if (arq == NULL){ //verifica se ocorreu erro
   printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo\n");
   return;
}

strcpy(Str, "testando"); //passa a plavra para variavel
resultado = fputs(Str, arq); //grava variavel no arquivo

if (resultado == EOF){ //verifica se ocorreu erro
   printf("Erro na Gravacao\n");
}
fclose(arq); //fecha o arquivo
```

Não sei se conseguir de ajudar, mas espero que sim!