# Procurar strings dentro de arquivos *.txt em C

Tags: c, c++, txt

Eu sou iniciante e estou penando pra fazer um programa e C++ que requer fazer duas funções.

1) Procurar num arquivo *.txt por uma string específica;

2) Através de algum tipo de índice indicar a posição desta string dentro do arquivo.

Pra tentar explicar melhor, por exemplo, eu tenho o texto "Nome: Luiz Fernando Oliveira". O que eu preciso é de um programa que ache a string "Nome:" e me indique a posição do arquivo para que eu consiga ler "Luiz Fernando de Oliveira" e salvar em outro arquivo.

Eu sei que tem bastante material sobre isso mas eu não consigo fazer as "peças se encaixarem". Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Grato desde já.

Comment: Porque não ler o conteúdo inteiro do arquivo, colocando-o em uma string `a` na memória e então procurar `Nome:` dentro dessa string, retornando a posição onde foi encontrada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você precisa é:

1. Abrir o arquivo de entrada.
2. Determinar o tamanho do arquivo.
3. Colocar todo o conteúdo do arquivo em uma string na memória.
4. Procurar por `Nome:` nessa string, encontrando a posição adequada.
5. Separar o nome em uma outra string.
6. Abrir o arquivo de saída.
7. Escrever no arquivo de saída.
8. Fechar ambos os arquivos.

Para abrir o arquivo, use a função `fopen`. No passo 1, você deverá abrir no modo leitura binária (`"rb"`). No passo 6, use o modo de escrita binária (`"wb"` ou `"ab"`). [Veja essa minha outra resposta para ter mais detalhes.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42564/132)

Para fazer o passo 2, de acordo com [essa minha resposta antiga](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44394/132), use isso:

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
int sz = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

No passo 3, você usa um `malloc` para alocar memória suficiente para a string e use o `fread` para ler o conteúdo do arquivo.

Uma possível forma de fazer o passo 4 seria:

- Faça uma função que busca uma string dentro de outra string. `int busca_string(char *agulha, char *palheiro, int tamanho_agulha, int tamanho_palheiro)`. A analogia usada é a de buscar uma agulha no palheiro, onde o palheiro é o conteúdo do arquivo e a agulha é o que você procura lá.
- Nesta função, você pode usar dois laços `for` um dentro do outro. O laço externo percorre cada caractere da string lida do arquivo (o `palheiro`). O laço interno compara a partir da posição do laço externo, se os caracteres encontrados no `palheiro` correspondem a mesma sequência dos caracteres que você está procurando (`Nome:`, que é a `agulha`).
- Use `break` no laço interno quando o que você achar no `palheiro` não coincidir com o que você está examinando na `agulha`.
- Após o final do laço interno, mas ainda dentro do laço externo, verifique se o laço interno acabou, e caso tenha acabado, dê um `return 1;`.
- Se o laço externo terminar, dê um `return 0;`.
- Cuidado para não acessar memória além do limite de qualquer uma das duas strings.

O passo 5, eu não sei. Você não disse como você vai saber onde o nome que você procurava termina de forma que você possa separá-lo do conteúdo subsequente. Entretanto a posição inicial desse conteúdo é a posição resultante do passo 4 mais o tamanho da `agulha`.

Para o passo 7, use `fwrite`.

Para o passo 8, use `fclose`. Não se esqueça de chamar o `free` para cada `malloc`.

Se você preferir usar o modo texto ao invés do binário (`"r"`, `"w"` e `"a"` ao invés de `"rb"`, `"wb"` e `"ab"`), troque o `fwrite` por `fprintf` e o `fread` por `fgets`. Mas neste caso, o tamanho da área de memória alocada pode acabar por ser insuficiente se ocorrer conversões de quebras-de-linha do tipo `\r -> \r\n` ou `\n -> \r\n`. Assim sendo, recomendo usar o modo binário na leitura. Na escrita, use o modo que achar melhor (mas para evitar surpresas, talvez seja melhor ater-se ao binário).

Comment: Muito obrigado Victor! Clareou bastante as ideias aqui.